# Using lambda in java 8 in android studio

Tags: java, android, lambda

I am using java 8 with lambda expression and got this error
My code is below:

```
Predicate<Site> predicate = c-> c.id == filter.get(0);
```

and received error below:

```
12-05 10:57:44.745 25416-25416/khabarazma.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: khabarazma.com, PID: 25416
                                                                java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: chitva_Pages.-$Lambda$17
                                                                    at chitva_Pages.Search$LoadFilter.lambda$-chitva_Pages_Search$LoadFilter_lambda$20(Search.java:3787)
                                                                    at chitva_Pages.-$Lambda$8.$m$0(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at chitva_Pages.-$Lambda$8.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4455)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18448)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5064)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Have you set everything needed described on [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)?

You should configure Gradle for java8 features:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the link as well